# Why does Rust code using printf in a loop from C not display output, but using std::cout in a loop from C++ does?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, while-loop, rust

I use Rust to call a C function with a loop (`for` or `while`), which uses `printf` function to display something, but the C function doesn't display any output from `printf`.

C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_c() {
  int s = 3;
  while (1) {
    printf("%d\n", s);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

However, when using C++, output is successfully generated.

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern "C" {
  int print_it(int32_t num) {
    while (1) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
  }
}
```

C is packaged as a shared library named "cthread". C++ is named "cppthread".

This is the Rust calling the C library:

```rust
#[link(name = "cthread")]
extern "C" {
    fn print_c();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { print_c() };
}
```

And the Rust calling the C++ library:

```rust
#[link(name = "cppthread")]
extern "C" {
    fn print_it();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { print_it() };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "stop being unusable" ...?

Comment: What you say don't make any sense

Comment: sorry,my description is wrong, it should be loop can't display the contents of printf.

Comment: Also I think you should include your rust code. Read [mcve].

Comment: Just a wild guess because there's no verifiable example. Besides the parameter and return type, the biggest difference is that the C version does not flush stdout. The C++ version uses `std::endl`, which has an implicit flush to stdout (that is the reason the use of `std::endl` is discouraged). Forcing a similar flush in the C version with a `fflush(stdout)` might be the cause.

Comment: That definitely because you write on a fully buffered stdout. Also, your call of `print_it()` is invalid and exposed to undefined behavior.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Rust. Please divide-and-conquer more in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your C and C++ versions are not equivalent.**

Your C version just prints a number and a newline. It does no explicit flushing (which is then left up to various layers of the I/O stack to decide when to do — almost certainly, given your `sleep(1)`, this will take some time!).

Your C++ version prints a number, then (via `endl`) both prints a newline and flushes. That's why you always see the result straight away.

**`os << endl` is `os << '\n' << flush`.**

Making your C version do this as well is easy, using [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_c() {
  int s = 3;
  while (1) {
    printf("%d\n", s);
    fflush(STDOUT);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

This problem has nothing to do with Rust.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your C version and it worked for me in macOS. As you did not tell us your operating system, it's hard to know if it's something platform specific. Try adding a `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_c() {
  int s = 3;
  while (1) {
    printf("%d\n", s);
    fflush(stdout); // This makes sure stdout is not being buffered.
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

---

As for your C++ version, it has its own problems in the Rust code.

Since your C++ version returns an int, and takes an int as a parameter. You need to define your extern definition to show that. Since you actually take an `int32_t`, I used the `i32` for the type. But you return an `int` *(note: you don't actually return anything in your code).*, and because the size of an `int` can be different on different platform, it's best to use the `libc::c_int`

```rust
extern crate libc;
use libc::c_int;

#[link(name = "cppthread")]
extern {
    fn print_c(num: i32) -> c_int;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { print_c(10) };
}
```